# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property <property_name> of undefined

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, axios

I am receiving this error when I try to access the JSON file I create in backend. So I have used Node.js as my middleware to access database into my react js, which sends back a JSON response.
The backend part (FetchDB.js):

```
routing.get('/viewTableData', function(req, res, next)
{
  pool.connect(function (err, client, done)
  {
    if(err)
    {
      console.log("Can't connect to DB"+err);
    }
    client.query('SELET * from MyTable', function(err, result)
                  {
                    done();
                    if(err)
                    {
                      console.log(err);
                      res.status(400).send(err);
                    }
                    var toSend = {rows:[]};
                    toSend["rows"] = result.rows;
                    res.status(200).send(toSend); 
                 })
         })
})
```

Refer to the comments (line 1 and line 2) of ViewList.js where I am facing the issue. In Line 1, it's showing me the exact data as expected in json format. However, when I try to access the keys of the json file, I get the above mentioned error. When I use typeof for **this.state.list**, I get **object** in the console, and **undefined** for **this.state.val.rows[0].createdDate**. The json response as observed in Postman is as follows:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "createdDate": "cr_date1",
      "lastModifiedDate": "mod_date1",
      "jsonData": "some_data_1_is_here"
    },
    {
      "createdDate": "cr_date_2",
      "lastModifiedDate": "mod_date_2",
      "jsonData": "some_data_2_is_here"
    },
    {
      "createdDate": "cr_date_3",
      "lastModifiedDate": "mod_date_3",
      "jsonData": "some_data_3_is_here"
    }
}
```

ViewList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ViewList extends Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: {
        "rows" : []
        }
      }
    this.callMe = this.callMe.bind(this);
  }

  callMe()
  {   

    axios.get('http://localhost:4321/viewTableData')
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          val: res.data,
        })
      })

  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.callMe();
  }

  render()
  {

    console.log(this.state.val);                                          // line 1
    console.log(this.state.val.rows[1].createdDate);                      // line 2

    return (
        <p>some text here</p>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Typo in select statement

Answer (score 0):

Thats because initially your val `State` has empty string and it does not have `rows` object:

```
val: {
        "rows" : []
      }
```

Try to log after this condition i.e.

```
if(this.state.val.rows){
   console.log(this.state.val.rows[1].createdDate);    
}
```

Comment: I tried, the condition returns true and the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Dale Coms, there is a typo in your SELECT statement which probably results in empty response from the database server, thus no JSON to be passed forwards.

You are writing SELET instead of SELECT on line

`client.query('SELET * from MyTable', function(err, result)`.

It should be:

`client.query('SELECT * from MyTable', function(err, result)`.